# Does my life insurance company have to tell me the interest rate for borrowing on my cash value before I process the loan?

Tags: interest-rate, insurance, interest, life-insurance, whole-life

I have a permanent (whole life) insurance policy.  I want to take out a loan on my cash value, so I called the company to get information.  The company representative told me that they would give me the information after I process a loan; it would be sent in the mail.  The company wouldn't tell me the interest rate over the phone.  Don't they legally have to tell me the rate before I decide whether or not to process a loan with them?

Comment: Please edit and add country tag

Answer (score 2):

They didn't tell you, probably because they didn't know themselves.  Like an auto loan or mortgage, where you've got to fill out "paperwork" and let them do a credit check.

On the Whole Life policy which my grandparents purchased in my name, I just called the salesman and he told me over the phone.  Thus, my guess is that some companies have fixed rates, and others variable.

Comment: If I start processing the loan, do they have to give me the rate within so many days?

I just didn't understand why they couldn't tell me.  When I called previously (although that was months ago), they told me everything I needed to know.

Comment: That part, I don't know.

Comment: Why would an insurance company need to run a credit check when they are lending you your own money?